# Is user_photos needed?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Please excuse the elementary question but I am pretty confused on requesting Facebook permissions for my app. My app allows users to select photos then login to their facebook page and those photos are posted on their timeline. I am requesting manage_pages, publish_pages, and publish_actions. In my developer account I added two testers who are friends of mine and we thoroughly tested the process. Everything works perfectly. But when I created a Test User (the one where facebook creates a generic account) my app doesn't post photos to their wall. I granted the test user the same permissions. I am now wondering if I need to call user_photos as another requested permission. I don't think I do since I am not requesting access to the users photos or albums. I am simply posting photos to their timeline which I thought is what publish_pages and publish_actions does. Can you look at the code and see if you can find what I am doing wrong?

```
  - (IBAction)facebookButtonClicked1:(id)sender
{


   if ([self.selectedImages count] > 0)
   {


  FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
   [login logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
    fromViewController:self
    handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Process error");
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Logged in");

             [self shareSegmentWithFacebookComposer];


        }
    }];

   }
  else
  {
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Photos"    message:@"You have not selected any photo." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
   [alert show];
  }


 }

-(void)shareSegmentWithFacebookComposer{
if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]   hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {
    [self publishFBPost]; //publish
} else {
    NSLog(@"no publish permissions");
  }
  }

  -(void) publishFBPost{
 NSMutableArray* photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString* imageFile in self.selectedImages) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageFile]];
    FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
    photo.image = image;
    photo.userGenerated = YES;

    [photos addObject:photo];

}

FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = [photos copy];

[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
  withContent:content
        delegate:nil];
  [FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:nil];

viewThanks.hidden = NO;
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.5 target:self selector:@selector(start) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [FBSDKShareDialog new];

[shareDialog setMode:FBSDKShareDialogModeAutomatic];
  [shareDialog setShareContent:content];
 [shareDialog show];
}
```

Comment: Do you want to publish the photo onto the user’s personal timeline, or a page they manage – of both?

Comment: I want to just post a photo on their personal timeline but would it matter if it posted on a page they manage? Does publish_pages cover that?

Comment: Don’t ask for manage_pages and publish_pages, if you want to post to a user profile only.

Answer (score 0):

There were publish_stream permission to upload photos but in the latest SDK  **publish_actions** have replaced publish_actions so you only need publish_actions. And if you want to  see the user's photos then you need the user_photos permission.